# How do i create an online database for my crossplatform mobile and desktop apps?

Tags: database, ionic-framework, cross-platform, electron

I am creating project (tailoring app) which is used to store customers measurements. I am using ionic framework and i need database to access all these information on all devices . What should i use?. I am a novice and doing this for fun ...

Answer (score 0):

you Can create models (similar to database) in Backand, and the interesting thing is you can use rest API and you can access your models(database) ...

You can do the following ...

- ADD
- DELETE
- UPDATE
- and Etc ...

Link

```
http://www.backand.com/
```